# Regexp for catch any normal characters+numbers+space but no any other special character

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need a regexp that catch:

- normal characters
- numbers
- the `-`
- any space

I've tried with `/[a-z0-9\-]*/g` but while on https://regex101.com/r/Vpc7UX/1/ works almost perfectly (didn't recognize the spaces), it doesn't work at all when I use in javascript with:

`(/[a-z0-9\-]*/gi).test(text)`

While a simple `(/[^a-z0-9]/gi).test(text)` (that only accepts characters and numbers, no spaces and no `-`) works without any problem, so I guess that the regexp is wrong.

I want that works with:

- "Hello-World"
- "Hello world"
- "helloworld"
- "Hello      World"

but not with:

- "Hello@world"
- "Hello&world"
- "Hello_world"

Any help with regexp+javascript problem ? What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't Toto answer work for you? Note you should remove `g` from the regex in JS. If you want to only match regular spaces, not any whitespace, replace `\s` with a space. Use `if (/^[a-z0-9 -]*$/i.test(s))`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tWVEWK/1). If you need to match at least 1 char, replace `*` with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Use anchors and add spaces:

```
(/^[a-z0-9\s-]*$/gi).test(text)
  ^_______^^___^
```